# Why the OS executes lz4?

Tags: services

I have no scheduled backups but I saw that **lz4** was been executed, why is that? is it the same as the compressor software? I would like to understand what's going on and why it is been executed.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

[image: this is what I saw when executing top command]

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details, if you're asking about a desktop, server, device running specialist release...  (a quick `rdepends` query shows some possible causes for my own system; but your system maybe very different as you provided no specific details)

Comment: Try the command `ps -aef | grep lz4` to see the entire command line being used to execute `lz4`.

Comment: @guiverc you are right, I've added the details to the question

Comment: What is the output of `which lz4`, `dpkg -S $(which lz4)` ?

Comment: @N0rbert `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/lz4` and `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /home/user/anaconda3/bin/lz4` respectively

Comment: So this is because of anaconda. Check why it has background jobs.